# Angular Project deployed on Firebase but not showing the website

Tags: angular, firebase, deployment, firebase-hosting

I have deployed my angular project on Firebase but not showing the website.
While clicking the URL to see the website.it's showing this page 
[image]

and here is my Firebase CLI

[image]

Comment: I suspect that your Angular build directory isn't the same as the hosting one. Double check which directory `ng build` is building to, vs which directory is listed in `firebase.json`. Can you show where it's building to, and your firebase.json file?

Comment: What I do is with me atleast it create a public map. I just copy all files in there except the firebase config files and then deploy.

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing the entire CLI output, but I think that before the first line you had something like:

```
? File ./index.html already exists. Overwrite?
```

to which you have answered No, resulting in:

```
i  Skipping write of ./index.html
```

You should answer Yes to this question and overwrite the `index.html` file. As a matter of fact, the image you show at the top of your question is the default `index.html` file generated by the CLI when you create a project.

Comment: it didn't work for me.I resolve this issue in an another way
Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @rykamol what other way? care to share?

Answer (score 0):

You could clear command cache and it'll do, it works for me

if you are using VScode, type `Ctrl + Shift + p`, then type clear command cache. 
After that build your project again `firebase build --prod`, then deploy `firebase deploy`.
Then you are set to go (: